# Back to QGIS 3.10 from QGIS 3.12 in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: qgis-3, ubuntu, linux

I've followed this steps to install QGIS in linux. In the past, it worked fine to install QGIS 3.10, which I want. Now, this code install QGIS 3.12. What should I change to get 3.10?.

```
# edit sources.list and add deb lines
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

deb     https://qgis.org/ubuntu eoan main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu eoan main

#public key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 51F523511C7028C3

#install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Comment: Accourding to the [install page](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) repository should be: `https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr` for long term release (3.10)

Comment: I've just added that part and this is the error: El repositorio «https://qgis.org/ubuntu-lrt eoan Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.

Comment: It should be "ltr" not "lrt", standing for "long term release".

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. It works ¡

Comment: 19.10!! A daredevil!!! just kidding, but I think sticking to LTR's for distributions lines up better with QGIS releases...